# InstallShield limited edition in visual studio 2012 on windows 10 gives BSOD

Tags: visual-studio-2012, installshield, bsod

I'm working with installshield 2013 limited edition in visual studio 2012. This used to work fine on windows 8.1. After upgrading to windows 10 installshield produces a BSOD: registry_filter_driver_exception; ISRegFlt64.sys problem.
This is a known problem for Flexera but they don't seem to offer an upgrade. 
Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

The fix is present in InstallShield 2015, including the 2015 Limited Edition. If you can't use that because of editions of Visual Studio, you should be able to just take the updated driver and replace it per (tweaked) [instructions on the community](https://community.flexerasoftware.com/archive/index.php?t-219114.html) (except for the bug fix, the driver is shared and hasn't changed lately):

> ... copy ISRegFlt.sys (ISRegFlt64.sys on 64-bit machines) from \Program Files (x86)\InstallShield\2015\System to the System folders of any other recent versions of [InstallShield] on the machine.